# How to update datatable object from jquery

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want to update datatable object by adding key=>value pair on the particular index like - below is my datatable object value. So i just want to add a key value pair under **column[0]['search']** index from jquery. I tried this
dataTable.columns(0).search({"Key":"value"}).draw(); but its not working.-

```
Array
(
    [draw] => 2
    [columns] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [data] => 0
                    [name] => 
                    [searchable] => true
                    [orderable] => true
                    [search] => Array
                        (
                            [value] => 
                            [regex] => false
                        )
```

`)

        [1] => Array
            (
                [data] => 1
                [name] => 
                [searchable] => true
                [orderable] => true
                [search] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => 
                        [regex] => false
                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [data] => 2
                [name] => 
                [searchable] => true
                [orderable] => true
                [search] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => 
                        [regex] => false
                    )

            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [data] => 3
                [name] => 
                [searchable] => true
                [orderable] => true
                [search] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => 
                        [regex] => false
                    )

            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [data] => 4
                [name] => 
                [searchable] => true
                [orderable] => true
                [search] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => 
                        [regex] => false
                    )

            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [data] => 5
                [name] => 
                [searchable] => true
                [orderable] => true
                [search] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => [object Object]
                        [regex] => false
                    )

            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [data] => 6
                [name] => 
                [searchable] => true
                [orderable] => true
                [search] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => 
                        [regex] => false
                    )

            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [data] => 7
                [name] => 
                [searchable] => true
                [orderable] => true
                [search] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => 
                        [regex] => false
                    )

            )

        [8] => Array
            (
                [data] => 8
                [name] => 
                [searchable] => true
                [orderable] => true
                [search] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => 
                        [regex] => false
                    )

            )

        [9] => Array
            (
                [data] => 9
                [name] => 
                [searchable] => true
                [orderable] => true
                [search] => Array
                    (
                        [value] => 
                        [regex] => false
                    )

            )

    )

[order] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [column] => 0
                [dir] => desc
            )

    )

[start] => 0
[length] => 10
[search] => Array
    (
        [value] => 
        [regex] => false
    )

[type] => mytask`

)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ajax.data`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data) option if you want to submit additional key/value pairs to the server.

For example:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "ajax": {
    "url": "data.json",
    "data": function ( d ) {
        d.extra_search = $('#extra').val();
    }
  }
} );
```